# Powering 2 servos with 5v output of L298N dual motor driver

Tags: gpio, pwm, electronics, battery, servo

I am using L298n Dual Motor Controller to control two dc motors for my robot. But I want it to power the servos too. I have created this circuit design.
[image]

can I power the SG90 Servo with L298n? Is there any fault in the circuit? Any Other suggestion will be appreciated.

**Specifications of components:**

**DC Motor** -

- Voltage range: *6-9V*
- Motor speed: *188RPM*
- Reduction ratio *45:1*

**Servos** -

- Torque   *25.0 oz-in (1.80 kg-cm) at 4.8V*
- Voltage  *4.0V to 7.2V, 4.6V - 5.2V nominal*
- Running current with 5V supply (no mechanical load)  *220 ±50mA*
- Stall current with 5V supply (horn locked)   *650 ±80mA*
- Idle current with 5V supply  *6 ±10mA*

**Battery** - 
7.4v Lithium Ion Battery 2600Mah

**Motor Controller** - [L298n](http://www.amazon.in/Robodo-Electronics-Motor-Driver-Module/dp/B00N4KWYDE?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=ox_sc_act_title_7&smid=A3H5F6BJA0G125)

Comment: What does this have to do with the Pi?

Comment: I am using pi to control everything. I am using Pi instead of Arduino is because I am adding many features to my robot car, including voice assistant and much more.

Comment: I am trying something similiar with lego motors. I voted this question up. Can you please post your results. What I usually see with motor shields, is that the servo is connected directly to the shield. So this would be an inexpensive alternative.

Comment: This is not a question, it's a review request.

Comment: @AnshulBansal did you get this one to work? I have a similar setup but I have problems with servo jittering when running the motors.

Answer (score 1):

That will be fine.

Servos and DC motors are quite power hungry so don't expect the battery to last very long.

Comment: I am using these cells in series. http://www.amazon.in/Genuine-LG-Rechargeable-Lithium-Battery/dp/B01M3TD8CF?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=ox_sc_act_title_3&smid=A1JL72BPO5JEIM

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://www.addicore.com/Addicore-SG90-Mini-Servo-p/113.htm) the power required for the servo is around 200mA (but yours may be a different module, check the current requirements for your own model).

So with 2 of them you'd need the L298 Motor driver modules' onboard 5V to be able to provide 400mA.

Depending on the module it could be providing anything from 50mA to > 1A - check with regulator it uses and find the current it can provide.

Comment: Will the 7.4v battery provide enough volts for all four motors (4.8v-6v servo and 6-9v dc motor)?

Comment: Yes. It is not *volts* you need to be concerned with here, it is *current (Amps / milliamps)*

Comment: You might want to post datasheets for the motors, batteries and H bridge module you are using, as there are so many variations it's tough to say definitively...   and this question is really more suited to http://electronics.stackexchange.com/